# What is "adaptive optics retinal imaging"?

Tags: eye, medical-imaging, technology

A paper [says](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/31696163)

> To validate the effectiveness of using A-GAN for data augmentation, we assessed its performance on cell analysis in **adaptive optics retinal imaging**, which is a rapidly-changing medical imaging modality.

where "adaptive optics retinal imaging" seems some kind of medical imaging technique.

Is it

a technique inspired by retina

or

a technique for retina, to get something like this

[image]